# Как найти максимальное количество идущих подряд пробелов в строке

Tags: python

Нужно сделать это одной строкой (препод цикл вообще не принимает).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использование циклов под запретом, можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
from re import findall
print(len(max(findall('\s+', 'this     is   test string') or [''])))
```